# The USA "self-employment tax dodge" mystery

Tags: united-states, taxes, self-employment, s-corporation

For non-US readers:

In the US, for those who are self-employed, there are many **specific** taxes. One **particular** tax is the confusingly named *"The Self-Employment Tax"*.

Thus, if you are self-employed, you pay **a number of specific** taxes, all of which have **various confusing names**.  (Here's a random example! The *"Individual Shared Responsibility Payment"* - !)

One **particular** tax, of the many that self-employed people pay, is the (confusingly named!) *"The Self-Employment Tax"*.

So, this QA is in fact about that particular tax, *"The Self-Employment Tax"*.

---

First I will explain how I believe self-employment tax works in the US:

- Sally makes $200,000 in the year. She is paid as a ordinary 1099 worker.
- She pays S.E. tax of about $20,000 on that.

*(Note for overseas readers who are following along.  So, among the various/many taxes she pays, **>>one<<** of them is the "S.E. tax" - $20,000 in the example.  This QA is only about the "S.E. tax" specifically.)*

~ Alternately ~

- Sally sets up an LLC which will be treated as an SCorp (or, she just sets up an Scorp)
- The SCorp gets $200,000
- The SCorp pays her $100,000 income
- The SCorp gives her $100,000 profit distribution
- Sally pays only $10,000 S.E. tax (ie, on the 100k income portion)
- Sally undeniably seems to **save $10,000**

What is my question:

it seems "too good to be true." (Especially in the USA!)

In fact, is the above actually correct?

So my exact question: *for Sally who makes $200,000 in 1099 income as her total income, is it a flat fact that she can save (about) $10,000 simply by using the "SCorp dodge" described?*

Are there any gotchyas, or other aspects that in fact eliminate the huge gain?

(I have already heard that the "salary" (so, 100k above) has to be "reasonable", let's assume that in the example given it is "reasonable".  I also appreciate there are other unrelated benefits in the US to the corp approach - say, simply being able to deduct expenses better, etc etc. Here I'm just asking about the "Self-employment tax dodge!")

cheers!

Comment: it gets *even better* under the pass through income laws and the new tax plan with the corporate tax rate.

Comment: It's not so much a tax dodge as a paying more taxes because of employing yourself.

Comment: This is *precisely* the approach that is getting people into trouble for "tax avoidance" in the UK - many celebrities and personalities have been fined by HMRC for using these style of "employ thy self as a company" schemes in recent years, so ultimately it doesn't pay off if the IRS decide its an non-legitimate approach to reducing ones tax burden.

Comment: why is Sally only making the same amount as a self employed contractor ? normally your make 2-3x your rate as an employee when going self employed

Comment: Related: [What is a reasonable salary for the owner and sole member of a small S-Corp?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/36818/10997)

Comment: _"Sally makes $200,000 in the year. She is paid as a ordinary 1099 worker."_ Wow, I want to move to where an "ordinary worker" makes $200,000 per year!

Comment: lol @LightnessRacesinOrbit, really.

Comment: hi @Neuromancer - you may have misunderstood the question.  in **both** cases she is 1000% self-employed.  She used to be a normal employee at Microsoft on the payrolls, making $80,000 plus the usual benefits.  Now she is a self-employed contractor for startups in the bay area. As you say she had to triple her weekly rate once she became self-employed.  OK?  (In the US if you are self-employed, there are two "methods" to do that: "1099 method" or "SCorp method".  this question is about the difference between the two methods.)

Comment: hi @Moo - this question is 1000% about the USA case.

Comment: @Fattie so? Can't I point out that it's a well known tax avoidance scheme the world over, to the point where other tax collection agencies are coming down hard on its use?  Seems kinda relevant to someone looking to use it, in that the IRS might follow suit...

Comment: In the SCorp case, isn't Sally effectively an employee of the SCorp. 
 And then the SCorp have to also pay "payroll taxes" that are on the order of the self-employment tax, right?

Comment: Doesn't SCorp have to pay corporate taxes on all $200k?

Comment: @NeilG - no, not at all.  the 100 is gone as salary, a cost

Comment: Right, but those $100k would have been taxed if you'd directly collected it as personal income.  This strategy is only interesting insofar as you defer income to later years.  And any such deferred income will be taxed as corporate profit, and then again taxed as personal income when you eventually take that as a salary.

Comment: hi @NeilG, you're completely wrong. Surprisingly, >that same year< you can pay out the corporate >profits< (separate from >salary<) to yourself.

Comment: Neil & Adrian - I suggest you ask a new question about this ........ and Pete.B. will answer it !  :)  Cheers

Comment: Neil & Adrian ... https://obliviousinvestor.com/s-corporation-tax-introduction/  "S-corporations, like partnerships, are pass-through entities. That is, there is **no federal income tax levied at the corporate level.**"   Just to be clear. In this question I was asking about **one specific** aspect of the whole LLC-SCorp affair.  The whole topic has many surprising aspects.  Here, I was just asking about one specific thing.

Comment: also @AdrianMcCarthy - I think (but I don't know - why are y'all asking me?!) in using this "fiddle" you do indeed have to have the LLC-SCorp pay a payroll tax (I think), but you come out ahead.  There's an example in the chart in this essay .. https://www.businessattorneyinaustin.com/tax-benefits-s-corporation-s-corp/

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You pretty much have it straight.  In the first case, for 2017, She would have to pay 12.4% (social security) on 127,200 of salary and 2.9% (medicare) on the full amount.  That would be $15,772, and $5,800 for a total of $21,572.

In the second case, she would pay at total of $15,300.

In the case you cite there is pretty much no downside to achieve the ~$6,000 savings except perhaps for the increase in tax preparation.  Filing as an S-Corp LLC can cost at least double that it takes to do a standard business return.  Even if the person does the taxes themselves, this indicates the complexity.

Now let's say instead that instead Sally decides to take a salary of 30k per year, increasing her SS tax savings dramatically (21572-4590=16982).  That has some consequences:

- Doing this long term will lower her social security payout.
- She could trigger an audit by the IRS and they could find that she is being too underpaid.
- If she becomes disabled, and is relying on social security disability her benefit may be drastically reduced.
- If she is in a partnership, all partners would also be required to participate in the dividend disbursement.

So there are drawbacks.  For the numbers you are suggesting, saving 6k when making 200k does not seem like the increase in complexity is worth it.

The far better benefit takes place in being able to do a solo-401K.  There Sally could do her 18K max, but also the company can contribute 25% of profits as a match.  In this case, that would be over 50K.  Sally could easily meet the 54k max (2017), greatly outpacing her peers for retirement savings and saving money on her top marginal rate.

Comment: Imagine Sally making $500,000 from clients.  *Assuming* she could get away with a "reasonable" salary of 100k, the saving would be spectacular - am I right or does it fall apart somehow at higher figures???  Cheers!

Comment: It does not fall apart at higher numbers, I know people that do this at numbers greater than you are talking about.  Taking salaries in the 300K range but distributing millions.

Comment: The case I am citing is a privately owned company.  However, the same thing is true with stock options.  No social security attached to those.

Comment: I guess it makes perfect sense when you think about it. Say I own, whatever, a large restaurant. It happily makes me $2m a year.  That "really isn't" salary, it's "really" the business making me $. Makes total sense of course.  Man, there must be people in a "middle range" who get hell from the IRS about this, and the whole "reasonable" thing must be a dog at moderate incomes!  Fascinating stuff

Comment: @Fattie - once your salary is over $127K the gain by switching to distributions is only 2.9% (and then 3.8% over $200K). So it still exists, but to a much lesser extent then it does before hitting the SS cap.

Comment: BTW @PeteB. i didn't ask a more basic question, *".. on 127,200 of salary .."* so that's like the limit on that part of the calculation eh?

Comment: This trick wouldn't work on Brasil since the profit distribution still counts as regular income. You would actually be taxed even _more_, since companies have to pay taxes over their employees.

Comment: Great answer @PeteB., I asked a follow up question here (https://money.stackexchange.com/q/93528/30539) that seemed too detailed for a comment...

Comment: I'd really like to see this answer for 2018.  I still haven't figured out the changes to S-Corp pass-thru income taxation.

Comment: I think it needs to be pointed out here that this answer is only talking about social security and medicare taxes, but readers could easily (mistakenly) think that this is about *all* taxes, particularly Federal Income Tax (which is not an "self-employment" tax), which is a much different story.  To be brief: *profits* from your S-Corp count as *personal income* to you for income tax purposes.

Comment: The upshot of this is that the tax savings from this strategy is primarily from the 2.9% medicare tax.

Comment: hi @RBarryYoung - hmm, it seems very clear in my question that the QA is only about the "self-employment tax" tax.  But sure, it's always worth pointing out!

Comment: The problem is that not everyone reading this may realize that the term "self-employment tax" is a formal term referring specifically to social security and medicare, rather than an informal descriptive term referring to any/all taxes paid by someone who is self-employed.  I for instance did not realize this when I first read it here.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thanks for the clarification. As a non-American, I didn't make this distinction. I thought this was *all* takes and couldn't figure out why the tax rate was so low and why the IRS doesn't charge taxes on profit distribution.

Comment: hi @stanri - I added an additional explanation for non-US readers. Please review!  :)

Comment: Where does the $15,300 number come from? I like how you broke it down with the $21,572 number. Could you do the same with the $15,300?

Comment: @Ben.12 it is just salary times the social security factors.  I looked them up when I did the math for this answer.

Answer (score 7):

On the surface I agree with the previous responses, however, since you are for tax purposes an employee, some states will require to you to carry workman's compensation insurance, and unemployment insurance (state & federal). In addition, there could be a higher income tax rate of the IRS believes you are a personal service corporation. Something not generally thought of as a positive is you social security income on retirement which can be higher based on your annual salary. However, there is an allure to the S Corporation.

Comment: In practice, most states exempt single-employee corps/passthroughs from worker's compensation. Also, the new tax law eliminates the higher tax for personal service corporations -- all C-corporations pay 21%.

Answer (score 2):

You are fundamentally wrong. The self-employment tax is actually not really a tax per se. It is the part of your FICA taxes that ordinarily would be paid by the employer.

The ordinary FICA tax rate *for employees* is 6.2% for Social Security, plus 1.45% for Medicare (7.65% total), up to the cap. In addition, the employer pays the same amount, called payroll taxes.

If you work on a 1099, your self employment tax is simply the sum of these two, or 15.3%. Half of that is tax deductible (because the employer part for an employee is also tax deductible).

The following is slightly simplified and not 100% accurate, but will give you the idea.

Let's say Sally works on a 1099 and makes $100k. Assuming no other deduction, her self employment tax would be $15,300.

If she funnels the money through a corporation, she would be an employee of that corporation. The corporation would pay $7650 in payroll taxes, and she would pay $7650 in FICA taxes.

Now if the corporation only paid her $50k as salary, and another $50k as profit distribution, you would be theoretically correct - but the IRS would go after her for tax evasion. Converting earned income (a salary or the like) into unearned income (profits, dividends) is illegal for exactly that reason.

In the end, of course sometimes profit distributions *are* legitimate. The IRS would look at the totality of the circumstances. But what you described sounds like a fairly obvious case.

Comment: Hey Kevin, I would just add the caveat that it is very, very commonplace in the US that people do - let us say - "get away with this" to a moderate degree.

Answer (score 0):

First of all SE tax tops out at income around 100K.  That is, if one earns  200K, SE tax is only calculated on the first 100K.  So the example doesn't quite illustrate the question.

Second, SCorp earnings are recognized by shareholders as they occur.  So the 200K the SCorp earns has to be considered as income by the shareholders regardless of whether the income was paid out or not.

So, Earning through an SCorp will have almost no effect on actual total taxes owed.

Comment: There is already an answer that explains your first point better.  Note that the Medicare portion of self-employment tax covers all income and even increases at higher incomes.  And I don't think that you are properly describing your second point.

Comment: To the second point: Passive income isn't taxed the same as earned income, so it does matter.